# Kotlin livedata observer not triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, observers

i'm practising a bit with kotlin and was testing Room and livedata, my app gets data from a json and the stores it in  room, i want to move this network call to its own file and class, but if i do so the observer i set to get the changes don't trigger anymore, any help would be appreciated

here is a snipped of my mainactivity, if more is needed to know what happens please let me know

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.room.Room
import com.optiva.videoplayer.data.*
import com.optiva.videoplayer.network.GetData
import com.optiva.videoplayer.network.Networking
import com.optiva.videoplayer.network.RetrofitConnect
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val dbcategories = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, CategoriesDatabase::class.java,"categories.db").build()
        val dbvideo = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, VideosDatabase::class.java,"videos.db").build()


        val retrofitData = RetrofitConnect.retrofitInst?.create(GetData::class.java)
        val categoriesList = retrofitData?.getAll()

        categoriesList?.enqueue(object: Callback<DataList> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<DataList>,
                response: Response<DataList>
            ) {
                val test = response?.body()
                val cat = test?.categories
                val vid = test?.videos

                lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    if (cat != null) {
                        for(c in cat){
                            dbcategories.categoriesDAO().insertAll(CategoriesEntity(c.id,c.title,c.type))
                        }
                    }
                    if (vid != null) {
                        for(v in vid){
                            dbvideo.VideosDAO().insertAll(VideosEntity(v.id,v.thumb,v.videoUrl,v.categoryId,v.name))
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DataList>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        })
        val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.test) as TextView
        dbcategories.categoriesDAO().getALL().observeForever({categories ->
            if(categories.size>0){
                textView.text= categories[0].title
            }
        })

        dbcategories.categoriesDAO().getALL().observe(this,  {categories ->
            if(categories.size>0){
                textView.text= categories[0].title
            }


    }
} ```
````